# doctrine 2.3.4 cannot find repository (class_parents(): Class does not exist and could not be loaded)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

this is my folder structure.

```
php-orm
    doctrine
        Amphur.php
    vendor
        bin
        composer
        doctrine
        symfony
        autoload.php
    list.php
```

this is list.php file.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$paths = array(__DIR__ . '/doctrine');
$isDevMode = true;
$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => $db[$dbuse]['username'],
    'password' => $db[$dbuse]['password'],
    'dbname' => $db[$dbuse]['database'],
);
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$class_repo = $entityManager->getRepository('Amphur');
//$provinces = $class_repo->findBy('', array('PROVINCE_NAME' => 'ASC'), 50, 0);
$provinces = $class_repo->findAll();
print_r($provinces);
```

this is doctrine/Amphur.php file.

```
<?php
// doctrine/Amphur.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="amphur")
 **/
class Amphur
{


    /** @AMPHUR_ID @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $amphur_name;


}
```

database: test_db
table: amphur [AMPHUR_ID|AMPHUR_CODE|AMPHUR_NAME|GEO_ID|PROVINCE_ID]

and when i run, i got error **Warning: class_parents(): Class Amphur does not exist and could not be loaded**

how to get repository if i already have existsing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the Amphur file to get rid of the class not found.  Later you can look at how to configure the autoloader to find files in the doctrine directory.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'doctrine/Amphur.php';
```

Also need to add an Id annotation to Amphur

```
/** @AMPHUR_ID 
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer") 
 * @GeneratedValue 
 * **/
protected $id;
```

Here is a debugging hint.  Take your error message and copy/paste it into the google search bar.  You might be surprised at how many solutions exist.

Comment: for Amphur class, use this to PK.

[at] Column(type="integer", name="AMPHUR_ID")

thank you.